# Traps in bash with exec in a script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, interrupt-handling

I want to accomplish two goals in a bash script:

1. redirect output of a running script to a file and display it to the user at the same time
2. execute two "cleanup" traps on exit and Ctrl-C

So I have this code:

```
IO_LOG="io_stats_$(date_hm).log"
ST_LOG="stress_test_$(date_hm).log"

# redirect script output to a log
exec &> >(tee -a "$ST_LOG" >&1)

# track disk io use with iotop running in background
/usr/sbin/iotop -botk &>"$IO_LOG" &

# kill iotop on exit of the main script (where this code is located)
trap 'kill $(jobs -p)' EXIT

# remove io log on sigint
trap "rm -fv \"$IO_LOG\"" SIGINT

# do the testing while iotop is tracking disk io
custom_long_running_stress_test_program

# (normal exit)
```

Before adding `exec &>...` both traps ran reliably.

However, after adding it the trap of `SIGINT` doesn't seem to run.

Now, I verified empirically that `EXIT` trap works as intended, because it kills `iotop` process even when redirecting output of the main script to a file with `exec`. Background `iotop` doesn't die when the `EXIT` trap is commented out, with or without redirection and it is killed when it's on, again with or without output redirection (I wanted to make absolutely sure it works as intended in all four cases).

It's different with SIGINT trap:

- with redirection on the IO_LOG is *not* removed
- with redirection off the IO_LOG *is* removed (and `rm -fv` prints the name of the file)

Why is that? How can I make operation of `SIGINT` trap work as intended?

Comment: ? Is there no `wait` nor nothing below?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, there's a long running command below. Will add it.

Comment: You have to create mcve. I replaced `custom_long_running_stress_test_program` for `sleep 10000` and it works for me - after clicking `ctrl+c`, then `IO_LOG` is getting removed and the script termintes killing iotop. Can't reproduce, Bash 5.1.16 . What is the output of `BASH_XTRACEFD=3 bash -x ./your_script 3>&1`?